# What is the difference between Differential cross section, Rutherford scattering cross section and coulomb collision cross section?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, measurements, scattering-cross-section

I've been reading about cross sections and then I kind of got confused. What exactly is the difference between elastic scattering cross section, Differential cross section, Rutherford scattering cross section and coulomb collision cross section? Aren't these all elastic? Than why do we have so many terms?

- Maybe the coulomb cross section only applies for charged particles (like in a plasma  maybe), so in plasmas, the coulomb cross section describes everything? Does that mean that in plasmas or charged gases, there is nothing called the differential cross section or the rutherford cross section?

Comment: Yes, the Coulomb cross section is specific to charged particles.  Coulomb collisions are basically the same thing as Rutherford scattering.  I think "differential cross section" is too general to assign here though, as that term is used in numerous branches of physics.

Comment: So, when I point a particle beam at a plasma, would any other types of scattering or collisions take place apart from either fusion or Rutherford scattering?